# Bash: read .txt files from a directory and add column records and append it in the same text file

Tags: awk

I have got .txt files from a directory. Read each file and add column records and append it in the same .txt file. 
I tried to write code using awk command, but I see some errors in it. Help me resolve it. Thanks!

```
for file in *. txt; do
   awk - F' ' {$2+$3=var} >> "$file" 
done
```

Comment: you didn't post the input and final result. Why?

Comment: File1.txt 10 20 200

Comment: what is `var` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it isn't a good idea to read from and write to a file concurrently in the same command. I would separate these steps.

If the awk script is used in a shell the output can be stored in a variable temporarily. (A temporary file is also an option.)

```
#/bin/bash
for FILE in *.txt; do
  # process file
  OUTPUT=$(awk '{ printf " %s", $2 + $3 }' "$FILE")
  # add results to file
  echo "$OUTPUT" >> "$FILE"
done
```

Notes:

1. I couldn't interprete what `{$2+$3=var}` is intended to mean. I assumed it should be `var=$2+$3` where `var` denotes the result. (It's just speculation.)
2. I used `$( )` to redirect standard output of the enclosed command into a string which in turn can be assigned to a variable.
3. The awk script has to be quoted (at best with single quotes) as `$2` and `$3` may be accidentally interpreted by the bash itself (and thus making the awk script wrong).
4. The space is the default field separator – it is not necessary to mention it. If instead your text files are tab-separated it should be denoted (e.g. `awk -F"\t"`).

But, may be, I got you completely wrong. May be, you want to add a column with the sums of each resp. line. (As you didn't provide sample output this is unclear for me.) In this case, the awk script has to be changed slightly:

```
#/bin/bash
for FILE in *.txt; do
  # process file
  OUTPUT=$(awk '{ print $0" "($2 + $3) }' "$FILE")
  # make a backup (or comment next line if you prefer cold showers)
  mv "$FILE" "$FILE".bak
  # overwrite file with patched version
  echo "$OUTPUT" > "$FILE"
done
```

Note:

The command for tab-separated files would be:
`awk -F"\t" '{ print $0"\t"($2 + $3) }' "$FILE"`

Finally, a general note:

Modifying original files is a little bit dangerous. It does mean that the repeated execution of the bash scripts (the former as well as the latter) on the same set of files will modify the files again and again (with probably unintended results). Therefore, I always prefer the creation of files with a new name (e.g. with an additional suffix). If it is necessary to keep the original file names, I rename the original files (e.g. with an additional suffix `.bak`) before writing new files with identical names. Thus, unintended results can be easily undone by e.g.:

```
$ for FILE in *.txt.bak; do mv "${FILE}" "${FILE/\.bak/}" ; done
```